# How to get array index from html element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hey In my Vue application I have the opportunity to create several persons:

```
<div v-for="newContent in temp" :key="newContent.id" @click="showId(newContent.id)"  v-show="true">

        <!-- Head of part personal data -->
        <h4 class="person" style="margin-left: 0.95vw">Person 1</h4>

        <!-- Enter Person Data -->
        <testmodul1></testmodul1>      

        <div class="trash">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" @click="deletePerson()">Person löschen</button>
        </div>
        <hr />
</div>
```

If I want to add more persons, there is a button, which appends more of these person inputs:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="useIt()">Add more persons</button>

useIt(){
  this.temp.push({
    id:this.id+=1
  })
  console.log(this.temp);
},

data() {
return {
  id:0,
  temp:[{
    id:0,
  }]
};
```

},

Output of the console.log method in the console (clicked the add button 2 times):

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {id: 0}
1: {id: 0}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Now the following problem: Let's say for example we created 3 new persons. Now I recognize, that the second person is false and I want to delete it. When I click on the  of person 2 I want to get the array index of the html element. I have already tried this, but it does not really work well:

```
<div v-for="newContent in temp" :key="newContent.id" @click="showId(newContent.id)"  v-show="true">

showId(index){
  alert(index);
  }
```

Is there an other way how I could find out the index in the array of the html div I clicked?

Comment: "does not really work well" is meaning what exactly? What is alerted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check [Vue.js list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

You can iterate through array with both element and index like this:

```html
<li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
</li>
```

For your case:

```html
<div v-for="(newContent, index) in temp" :key="newContent.id" @click="showId(index)" v-show="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define index variable in v-for loop itself. Like

```
<div v-for="(person,index) in persons" :key="index">
    {{index}} //which is index of current item
</div>
```